# How to abuse the preg_replace code execution vulnerability in BT PenTesting Lab?

Tags: php

The BTS lab has a page with the following PHP code:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/btslab/header.php');
    if(isset($_GET['data']))
    {
        $data = $_GET['data'];
        $data = preg_replace('/(.*)/e', 'strtoupper("\\1")',$data);
        print $data;
    }
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/btslab/footer.php'); ?>
```

How should I format some malicious input as the 'data' parameter please?
I've tried various things like `?data=system('ls -lah')` without success.

If the directory listing will not work, is there a way to get it to execute `phpinfo();` please?

Thanks in advance of your kind response.

Comment: What is your PHP version? [That vulnerability is no longer present in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-changelog).

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic. That is the issue in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

As @Don't Panic kindly pointed out the issue I was having relates to the version of PHP installed on the server I am hosting the pen testing lab on.

For anyone else looking to test this vulnerability though, please see this link for some examples of malicious input: http://www.madirish.net/402

`<?php
$string = "phpinfo()";
print preg_replace('/^(.*)/e', 'strtoupper(\\1)', $string);
?>`